# Keep disabled fields disabled after enable the others

Tags: jquery, forms, input, disabled-input

I want to disable all fields in a form and after that, enable only those who has been enabled before. But when I try to do that, all fields (including the pre-disabled fields) will be enabled.

```
$('body').on('click', 'input[type="button"]', function() {
    disable_fields(true);

    setTimeout(function() {
        disable_fields(false);
    }, 1000);
});

function disable_fields(t) {
    var fields = $('input,textarea,select,[type="file"]');

    fields.each(function(index, element) {
        if($(this).is(':disabled')) {
            is_disabled = true;
        }

        console.log(fields.attr('name')+' - '+is_disabled);
        $(this).prop('disabled', t);
        console.log(fields.attr('name')+' - '+is_disabled);
    });
}
```

How can I accomplish this?

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/edgren/t59981y1/)

Comment: There is no way of telling which fields are originally disabled once you fire the `disable_fields()` function. One way is to store the `disabled` status of each field on document ready in the data attribute/object, and then only perform the toggling on fields that do not have the original disabled status.

Comment: Why would you deliberately enable fields that you don't want enabled? The whole problem could be easily avoided by not enabling those fields inside of the `enable_all` function (which would become badly named by the change, but it would make your life easier).

Comment: Because when I hit the button in a form, I want to disable all the fields. If any errors occurred, I want to enable those fields that was enabled before I hit the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment—once you start modifying the `disabled` property, there is no sure way of knowing which input element has been originally disabled. To do so, you will have to store the "original" disabled status in some kind of data structure, such as the `data()` object of the element in jQuery. I chose not to store it as the HTML5 data attribute so users cannot easily manipulate the behaviour by modifying the markup.

The advantage of this approach, even though it appears rather convoluted, is that you reserve the option to manually update which fields you want to revoke/reinstate the disable toggle at a later stage, by simply modifying the `.data('disabled')` attribute of the input elements.

The strategy:

1. Store the disabled states of all input elements on page load
2. When executing `disable_fields()`, only filter the input elements whose original disabled status is false. We don't have to touch the elements that are already disabled originally.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Store the original disabled status of all input elements
  var $fields = $('input,textarea,select,[type="file"]');
  $fields.each(function() {
    $(this).data('disabled', $(this).prop('disabled'));
  });

  $('body').on('click', 'input[type="button"]', function() {
    disable_fields(true);

    setTimeout(function() {
      disable_fields(false);
    }, 1000);
  });

  function disable_fields(t) {
    // Perform toggling only on fields that have data attribute of disabled set to false
    // i.e. not disabled on page load
    $fields.filter(function() {
      return !$(this).data('disabled');
    }).prop('disabled', t);
  }

});
```

```css
input[name="first"] {
  width: 250px;
}
input[name="second"] {
  width: 90px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="first" value="Disabled (and will keep being disabled)" disabled>
<input type="text" name="second" value="Not disabled">
<input type="button" name="button" value="Button">
```

Comment: Your solution works perfectly on jsFiddle :) Many thanks! Now to import it to my website, which think I will never want to disable the other fields. Haha! Anyhow :) Many thanks once again!

Comment: @Erik If you do not want to modify the subset of elements that can be modified by the `disable_fields()` function, **[A. Wolff's answer is more than sufficient](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40059109/395910)**. Mine is just a future-proof solution ;) also updated my question because I forgot to load jQuery in the snippet.

Comment: Ok. I want a future proof solution ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can keep ref to not disabled fields by default by setting varibale outside `disable_fields()` function:

```
var fields = $('input,textarea,select,[type="file"]').filter(':not([disabled])');
```

### -jsFiddle-

Answer (score 0):

You need some other way to distinguish the fields which can never be enabled, since the simple attribute of being disabled isn't sufficient to identify them once all the others are disabled.

Assuming you know in advance which fields these will be, the easiest way is probably to give them all the same class, e.g. `always-disabled`.

Then when you're enabling your fields, you can exclude them from the list that you loop through to enable:

```
var fields = $('input,textarea,select,[type="file"]').filter(':not(.always-disabled)');
```